# Как в WordPress сделать выбор страницы, на которую будет выведен пост с определённой категорией?

Tags: wordpress

Есть шаблонная страница, которая будет дублироваться. На этой странице есть блоки, которые выводятся с помощью постов, на посты прикреплена категория.

Как сделать, чтобы пользователь мог выбирать — эти посты отобразятся на страница «А», а эти на странице «Б». При условии, что пользователь сам создал страницы?

P.S. Наверняка вопрос лёгкий, но это мой первый проект на WordPress и я не смог подобрать гугл-запрос для решения проблемы :(

Comment: Почему а задать этим страницам разные категории нельзя?

Comment: Потому, что делаю для клиента, если он добавит новую страницу, то не сможет наполнить её контентом

Comment: Лучше для каждого "типа страниц" создать разные "шаблоны".

Answer (score 2):

Засунуть код с циклом определенной категории в шорткод
Либо сделать шаблоны страниц с выводом определенных категорий.
Второе - не советую

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее про первый вариант? Сперва показалось, что понял, но всё таки не понял.